# Alternate method for Httpentity in OKHttpClient Library

Tags: okhttp, httpentity

I am trying convert HTTPClient method OKHttpClient, But i am not able to find the alternate method for HTTPentity and stringentity. Can Any one please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You want [RequestBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html) and [ResponseBody](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html) each of which have helper methods that work with strings.